# How to specify "all parameterized types" or "all argument lists" for a template class?

Tags: c++, c++03, dynamic-cast

Please forgive my ignorance in this area. I don't know what the concept is called, so I don't know what to search for.

I need to `dynamic_cast` to another interface, and then I need to call a method. However, the interface is parameterized, and I don't know how to say  "all parameterized types". That is I don't know how to do this (pseudo code):

```
template <class One, class Two>
class Foo : public Bar {...};

class Baz
{
    ...
    // Or Foo<*>& = dynamic_cast<Foo<*>&>(bar);
    Foo& foo = dynamic_cast<Foo&>(bar);
    foo.SomeMethod(...);
};
```

I get similar errors when attempting to C-Style cast. Its almost as if the compile won't proceed unless I select a specialization or instantiation (???), when all I want is to do is perform the same action on all of them.

The real code is a little more complex and the error is mostly incomprehensible. But the error is produced because I want to call a method that is present on a different interface, and I don't care what the parameters are.

How do I specify "all parameterized types" or "all argument lists" so I can get to the method present in the interface of interest?

---

Here's the error from Microsoft's compiler:

```
error C2955: 'Foo' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

Comment: @n.m. - Sorry for the late reply... I'm going to delete this question and ask a new one with the MCVE.

Comment: @n.m. - I was not allowed to delete the question, so I had to flag it for a moderator. Sorry about that. The new question with the MCVE is available at [How to specify “all parameterized types” or “all argument lists” for a dynamic_cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41049526)

Answer (score 1):

Different specializations of `class Foo` in your example are just different classes, there're no any relations between them, so, you cannot cast your object to the unknown class.

Hovewer, you could create an inheritance relation between these interfaces, like this:

```
// The interface containing everything which should be shared between Foo<T1, T2>
class FooBase : public Bar
{
public:
    virtual void SomeMethod(...) = 0;
};

// The specifics of Foo<T1, T2>
template<typename One, typename Two>
class Foo : public FooBase
{
...
};

// Usage example
class Baz
{
    ...
    FooBase& foo = dynamic_cast<FooBase&>(bar);
    foo.SomeMethod(...);
};
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... So should I `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast it to the type I need? I try to use `dynamic_cast` for the type safety, but if its the wrong tool for the job, then I'm happy to abandon it...

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is your choise here

Comment: @jww Please read this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Comment: OK, thanks. It looks like `dynamic_cast` was being used correctly. However, I forgot to declare `SomeMethod` as virtual. That is an absolutely useless error message...

Comment: @n.m. In the original code, `class Foo` is derived from `class Bar`, so, if `bar` is an object of `class Bar`, we need a `dynamic_cast` to cast down the inheritance hierarchy. Looks like I forgot to add this inheritance in my code, will update

Comment: Now I am at a more manageable error message: *"C2955: use of class template requires template argument list"*.

Comment: @n.m. On my machine this compiles ok, except for forgotten `;` after each class